# How to use Loops in teradata

Tags: database, teradata

I have my table like this :

```
 Id  Name  Country
 1    Vaibhav India
 2    Amit     UK
 3     Pranav  US
```

I want to read all the records by counting the max number of records present using  count(id) ,3 in this case  and just increment the counter by 1 for each records processed .Simultaneously i wanted to print the result of my counter variable.
     Can anyone suggest how to do it???

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results you want.  From your description, the `id` column has the properties you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Gordon!!!
just after the Country  column I wanted a counter column  that  would have values 1,2,3 for this example .
Sorry I tried presenting the results but these are just coming in a single row

Answer (score 0):

You already have the values `1,2,3`?

You might want a `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
Select Name, Country,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) -- or whatever column you want
from tab
```

Comment: I want the numbers in sequence ,here each time for a change in ID the qualifier will reset it self to 1, qualifier  would have been a good option if I would have same values for a column.

Comment: @vaibhavkumar: You don't do that in a relational DBMS, there's no meaning in a number like that because it might change at any time. Of course you can put a `ROW_NUMBER` in a view (and it's recommended to access the view layer instead of the base tables anyway).